# Proper use of invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, invoke

I have a general question about the usage of invoke. Most of my C# winforms projects have one backgroundworker and obviously a UI. Very soon I realise that I need information from the UI in my backgroundworker or I need to change the UI from my backgroundworker.
Example:

```
//example invoke usage to get information from UI (dateMatch = CheckBox, fromDate&toDate = Datepicker)
bool isDateMatch = false;
dateMatch.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { isDateMatch = dateMatch.Checked; }));
DateTime fromDt = new DateTime();
fromDate.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { fromDt = fromDate.Value; }));
DateTime toDt = new DateTime();
toDate.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { toDt = toDate.Value; }));
```

```
//example invoke usage to change UI (statusTxt = TextBox, progressBar = ProgressBar)
private void changeStatus(string statusTextV, bool enableProgressBar)
{
   statusTxt.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { statusTxt.Text = statusTextV; }));
   progressBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = enableProgressBar ? 1 : 0; }));
}
```

What I mean is that my code is full of invoke methods. Is this something bad and is there a better way to do this.

Comment: _"Is this something bad"_ - sounds like you are already aware :) .  _"is there a better way to do this"_ - yes `async/await`.

Comment: BTW, if you must stick with `Invoke()` consider using `BeginInvoke` instead.  The former can lead to a GUI main thread deadlock

Comment: can you give us a little more context? where and how is `changeStatus` called? ". Very soon I realise that I need information from the UI in my backgroundworker" why should that pose a necessity to invoke? Do you use the worker for a long lasting operation? how long does it last? minutes? hours? days?

Comment: I am sorry for the missing context. This example is not important or the program behind that, it was a general question about if this is the supposed way to use invoke. "why should that pose a necessity to invoke?" it's because I can't access the UI from the backgroundworker and I did not know a alternative. I will look into MickyD suggestion.

Comment: " I can't access the UI from the backgroundworker " actually your architecture should make such things unnecessary. If you would create a layer between the UI and the underlying model (lets call it viewmodel), then all updates on the UI could go into the viewmodel. And the Backgroudworker, which is working on the model could simply get all the values from the viewmodel, or be notified by it

Comment: @MongZhu This sounds like MVC, I somehow never thought about that within the context of C# winforms

Comment: "never thought about that within the context of C# winforms" I did neither in the beginning. But as soon as I started doing it, my life became much more comfortable. Also I started to write general invoke methods, because you will need them in case of event notification up to the GUI. For Example: `private void WriteTextToControlThreadSafe(Control control, string text)`

Comment: inside it you can do: `if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => control.Text = text));
            }
            else
            {
                control.Text = text;
            `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the controls will be on the *same* UI thread - the same as the form itself, so there is no need to do multiple invokes - and you can use simpler syntax:

```
private void changeStatus(string statusTextV, bool enableProgressBar)
{
   Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        statusTxt.Text = statusTextV;
        progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = enableProgressBar ? 1 : 0; 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `Invoke` again and again, it can be done in a single `Invoke`. About the proper use- controls are not thread-safe and are created on UI thread so you should access them in UI thread.

Let's suppose if you are accessing controls in other then UI thread you will have to write code to handle synchronization and have to lock the resource and all.

Comment: _"...and have to lock the resource"_ - even locks aren't sufficient for a thread-safe GUI.  Check-out _[Multithreaded toolkits: A failed dream?](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kgh/2004/10/19/multithreaded-toolkits-failed-dream)_

Comment: I am not sure this answer adds a lot at all.

Comment: This is the suggestion that MickyD made in the comment of my original question, I will definitely look into it.